# Displaying accented characters with pdcurses

Tags: c, windows, pdcurses

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(){

    initscr();

    for(int i = -128; i < 128; ++i)
        addch(i);

    getch();
    endwin();

}
```

[image]

Pdcurses is displaying blanks for characters -128 to 0 (128 to 255). Is there any way to get, at least, the accented characters such as é to display properly? `iostream` has no trouble:

```
int main(){

    for(int i = -128; i < 128; ++i)
    std::cout << char(i);

}
```

[image]

I compiled pdcurses with wide character and UTF support, although that's surely not the problem here anyway, right? (Since the characters I want are contained within 0-255, and using `add_wch` instead didn't solve the issue anyway).

Windows 10 64-bit with g++ 6.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very silly. `addch` takes a value of type `chtype`. The documentation isn't too clear on the actual type of `chtype` other than it represents characters. Looking at `curses.h` I can see that chtype is of type `unsigned long`. So the negative `i` values were being cast to `unsigned` and hence wrap around, causing curses to have to print characters for which their is no assigned ASCII representation. I was also getting lost because this seemingly similar code using no negative values produced the same result:

```
int main(){

    initscr();

    for(int i = 0; i < 255; ++i)
        addch(char(i));

    getch();
    endwin();

}
```

Until I remembered that char by default might be signed, and so `char(i)` of course wraps around to become negative before `addch` is called.